What is the ctags included with Emacs?
I'm not sure I understand the ctags that comes with Emacs?
Is this a totally original codebase and is not a fork of anything?
Does it say anywhere what languages it supports?

I can't tell you the history, but the ctags and etags programs provided with Emacs produce tags files in a format that Emacs understands, and it's worth noting that other ctags programs (https://ctags.io/ being the most notable at present) traditionally provide a command line option to generate the tags in the Emacs tags format -- so you generally have options to choose from when it comes to generating tags, and you can use whichever program works best for you.

See the wikipedia article on ctags for some history.

The original ctags was written by Ken Arnold.
It's a common programming tool used by many editors.
Emacs has its own implementation of ctags.
See https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lib-src/ctags.c:
#define CTAGS 1
#include "etags.c"

We can say that Emacs's fork of ctags is called etags.
The first commit is recorded at https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/c6d46f5f2eb7f142a9dd9284abbedae02776cfe4:
/*
 * Authors:
 *  Ctags originally by Ken Arnold.
 *  FORTRAN added by Jim Kleckner.
 *  Ed Pelegri-Llopart added C typedefs.
 *  Gnu Emacs TAGS format and modifications by RMS?
 *  Sam Kendall added C++.
 */



Does it say anywhere what languages it supports?

In its manual page.
It understands the syntax of C, Objective C, C++, Java, Fortran, Ada, Cobol, Erlang, Forth, Go, HTML, LaTeX, Emacs Lisp/Common Lisp, Lua, Makefile, Mercury, Pascal, Perl, Ruby, Rust, PHP, PostScript, Python, Prolog, Scheme and most assembler-like syntaxes.

Some Interesting Facts
The last line of the manual page of Universal Ctags (man ctags) is:

The section entitled "HOW TO USE WITH GNU EMACS" was shamelessly stolen from the info page for GNU etags.

man etags:

The etags program is used to create a tag table file, in a format understood by emacs;  
the ctags program is used to create a similar table in a format understood by vi.


You should read the manual. Chapter 29.4.2.2 Creating Tags Tables covers this:
29.4.2.2 Creating Tags Tables
.............................

The ‘etags’ program is used to create a tags table file.  It knows the
syntax of several languages, as described in *note Tag Syntax::.  Here
is how to run ‘etags’:

Following the link to chapter 29.4.2.1 Source File Tag Syntax takes us to a description of what sorts of things it makes into a tag for each language it supports. I won't include the whole list here; you can read it yourself to see the whole list. At the end of the chapter it says “You can also generate tags based on regexp matching (*note Etags Regexps::) to handle other formats and languages.”. That link goes to chapter 29.4.2.3 Etags Regexps which tells you how to craft regexes that match the constructs in your preferred language.

That’s weird...
